# How to get base URL in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to build a chrome extension which will get the Base URL of the page it is being called from, then concatenate with certain string and open up a new tab.

So, far I've tried the below code:

Manifest.JSON

```
{
  "name": "TEST APP",
  "version": "1",
  "browser_action":
  {
    "default_icon": "pepe.jpg"
  },
  "background":
  {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
    var base_url = window.location.origin;
    var newURL = base_url + "/MyPrivateURLString";
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});
```

When I load it and test, the Base URL is wrong and something like:

```
chrome-extension://lpcamgghpaemdddeopfgacgkdcmgdnfn/MyPrivateURLString
```

If I hardcode a full URL then it works fine. Why am I unable to use the base URL dynamically?

Comment: Maybe you want to check out how to get the currently active tab instead of the windows location

Comment: Is there a way we can get active tab base url?

Comment: Make sure to read the abut the extension architecture: the background script runs in a separate hidden background page with its own DOM and URL. What you need here is `activeTab.url`

Comment: `activeTab.url` will give me URL but I need the BaseURL. Is there a reason why `window.location.origin` is not working here?

Comment: The reason is explained in my comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got the solution. What was happening is that instead of giving me the base URL, the `window.location.origin` was giving me the origin URL where it is hosted at the moment, which was local.

So instead I used the `activeTab.url` and using the JS string manipulation, I got what I needed.

If anyone has a better way to do this, just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct in using `activeTab.url` instead of `window.location.origin` but instead of doing string manipulation, you can do following:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
    var url = activeTab.url; //Assuming it is working fine as per your post
    var urlObj = new URL(url);
    console.log('---urlObj--', urlObj);
});
```

This way you can get all the properties of the URL. For ex: For the current URL, you will get following details:

```
hash: "" 
host: "stackoverflow.com" 
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56509769/how-to-get-base-url-in-google-chrome-extension"
origin: "https://stackoverflow.com" 
password: "" 
pathname: "/questions/56509769/how-to-get-base-url-in-google-chrome-extension"
port: "" 
protocol: "https:" 
search: "" 
searchParams: URLSearchParams{} 
username: ""
```

Comment: Well this is what I needed. Will update my code.